# Concatenate in a PDF the first page of several odt files alphabetically

Tags: command-line, pdf

I have, in the same directory, several odt files.

I'd like to have in one PDF document the first page of these odt files, sorted alphabetically based on their filename.

For example, if I have these files:

- `a.odt`
- `b.odt`
- `c.odt`

I would have a resulting PDF that has 3 pages: the first one of `a.odt`, then the first one of `b.odt` and then the first one of `c.pdf`.

Does any one of you think about a command to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.odt; do
  echo "Converting [ $i ]"
  unoconv -f pdf "$i"
  echo "Extracting 1st page of [ $i ]"
  i="${i%odt}pdf"
  pdftk P="$i" cat P1-1 output "$i".1
done
echo "Merging pdfs"
pdftk *.1 cat output result.pdf
rm *.1
```

You have to install `unoconv` and `pdftk`.

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install unoconv pdftk`

Comment: You should probably use `pdftk` to merge the PDFs, not `convert`.  `convert` will rasterize all the pages, so the fonts and any vector artwork will be converted to bitmaps, increasing the size of the PDF and reducing its quality.

Comment: One downside to pdftk is that it doesn't preserve bookmarks and metadata. You *can* create a dump of all metadata but importing it has never worked properly for me. If preserving this data is important to you, you can always use an alternative like [sejda](http://www.sejda.org/) or [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/).